# IntelliJ (Webstorm / PyCharm) shortcut for take action now opens weird popup

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, macos-mojave

The default keyboard shortcut for `enter action` on an IntelliJ IDE on Mac is: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

When I enter this shortcut, a weird terminal popup opens up.

[image: Screenshot of weird terminal popup]

How can I go back to having this default shortcut working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is a result of clashing of default keyboard shortcuts for Mac Mojave OS and JetBrains IntelliJ IDEs. On Mojave by default <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> searches for the `man page` of whatever is highlighted. So any time after the first time you open the "enter action" popup on an IntelliJ IDE, you will have the previous action highlighted, and thus searched for by the default Mac Mojave shortcut.

Valid solutions:

1. On Mac go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> Search man Page Index in Terminal`. Either remove the shortcut, or set it to some other key combination.
2. Choose a different keyboard shortcut on IntelliJ IDE

It is also documented in the official YouTrack of JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209726

Comment: You actually saved my mental health. Thanks and may your family be blessed for 7 generations